# what is the answer of this indefinite integral?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

what is the answer of this indefinite integral? $$\int \frac{1}{x^{3}\cos^{2}(x)}dx$$
I have used all methods I knew, but all failed. some methods made it more complicated! please tell me your Ideas,that would be great.

Comment: I do not believe a "nice" anti-derivative exists. See [wolfram alpha query.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+1%2F%28x%5E3+*%28%28e%5E%28ix%29+%2B+e%5E%28-ix%29%29%2F2%29%5E2%29)

Comment: thank you very much.so what should we do with this kind of integrals?I mean that do we have a kind of expression for example with series  or continued fractions or we should put them away as they are?

Comment: The integrand has lots of infinite discontinuities (when $\cos x = 0$), so the best one could probably hope for is an expression for the definite integral across some nicely behaving region -- someone more experienced than I may be able to find out more.

Comment: (1) That some techniques make the problem more complicated, rather than easier, is usual in the integration biz. Get used to it. (2) What to do with the integral depends a lot on what you want to do with it. Sometimes, it is indeed best to leave it alone.

Comment: The integral $\int 1/(x^3(1+\cos^2 x))dx$ seems to behave more nicely. I do not know of a way to evaluate it though.

Comment: this is very good feeling when you know the Idea of others,thank you.

Comment: @EricThoma.I am just curious about your last statement. Could you elucidate ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Integrate by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts), using $\tan'(x)=\dfrac1{\cos^2x}$ . Then apply [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29) to $\displaystyle\int\frac{\tan x}{x^4}dx$ :-)

Comment: OK and then ? Cheers.

Comment: Lucian,I don't think that it is working,can you explain more?

Comment: Yes. The primitive of your little function is not expressible in terms of elementary functions. :-) Mind telling us where you found it ?

Comment: one of my friends ask me!I try your answer but no good result,how I should use Liouville's theorem?

Comment: It was a joke ! Just tell him it's a dead end. But if you're serious about it, see the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).